# Update: It's iPhone 4S week!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

This week, we’re kicking off a “Hot Topic of the Week” series.

How it works: One topic is designated each week, and each person who asks a question relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize. Topics are chosen from your suggestions in the community wiki below.

How to enter: Ask a question relating to the topic of the week, and tag it accordingly (this week, use the [iphone-4s](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone-4s) tag). Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win an iPhone accessory(s) of your choice ($100 max).

This round will begin today (Dec. 23) and end on Monday (Jan. 2).

Update: *Congratulations to [Allen Chao](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/15559/allen-chao) for [winning this week](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34708/is-my-iphone-model-number-mc922ll-a-unlocked-or-locked)! Thank you everyone who participated.* The weekly hot topic challenge is on hold for the next week. 
Please continue to add suggestions for upcoming weeks below!

Comment: Is everybody eligible or are there geographic restrictions?

Comment: Also: is it possible to advertise this on the site? I've seen small banners on philosophy.sx

Comment: Just an FYI: This holiday weekend has been relatively slow. We'll see if things pick up soon, but you may want to consider extending this 'week' a little longer.

Comment: Just curious: How is are the entries "collected" and how is the drawing done?

Comment: @Agos Everyone is indeed eligible, and there is a community banner ad on the side of the site up.

Comment: @Nathan Greenstein we may extend it, stay tuned for announcements.

Comment: @Moshe entries are sorted by the appropriate tag- one entry is chosen randomly.

Answer (score 6):

*Anyone can edit this! If you've got an idea, add it to the list.*

### Broad Topic Ideas

- iOS 5 [ios-5](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-5)
- OS X Lion [lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lion)
- next iDevice (after the actual product launch, of course), e.g. iPad 3
- iCloud [icloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icloud)

### Narrow Topic Ideas

- Apps / Software Recommendations [apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apps) and/or [software-recommendation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendation)
- Macs at work (business use)
- Hardware hacks
- Music & Media [itunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itunes) among other audio* tags.
- Command line fu [command-line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/command-line)
- Using Windows with OS X [windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows), potentially [virtualization](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualization), [parallels](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallels), [vmware-fusion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vmware-fusion), [bootcamp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bootcamp)
- Gaming on OS X [games](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games), [steam](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam)

Comment: Added some tags for the contest ideas. Wasn't sure about  those I left open, hopefully someone will tag them too. I think it's good to add tags for the topics already while suggesting: if the hot week topic can't be properly tagged, how could it be a good topic anyway? (And of course it is more practical for the contest manager to have the tags in advance.)

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a great idea!

The model would fit perfectly for our site, especially given the wealth of apps and accessories that would make perfect prizes.

I saw what happened on Andorid and was secretly hoping that you guys would offer to do something similar with us :)

I'm posting a separate CW answer for topic ideas.

Comment: Glad you like the idea! And thanks for taking the initiative to post the CW.